# W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found

Tags: java, android

Not able to locate address due to com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.

> 10-15 14:07:42.801 7646-7770/com.magicstudio.geomaps W/DynamiteModule:
>   Local module descriptor class for
>   com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found. 10-15
>   14:07:42.847 7646-7770/com.magicstudio.geomaps W/zygote: Skipping
>   duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader 10-15
>   14:07:42.857 7646-7770/com.magicstudio.geomaps I/DynamiteModule:
>   Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0
>   and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4 10-15
>   14:07:42.857 7646-7770/com.magicstudio.geomaps I/DynamiteModule:
>   Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates,
>   version >= 4

Gradile file dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.androi`enter code here`d.support.enter code heretest.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })enter code here
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'enter code here
}
```

Please help with this issue

Comment: Have you found any solution, I have the same issue.

Answer (score -3):

Try this : open the `sdk manager`, download/update `google play services`. Then click `build > rebuild`. Then create a new emulator.